# How are BigInteger stored

Tags: java, biginteger, bit, bigint

I need to generate 512 bit BigInts, but I'm not sure which of the two below is true:

512 bits means 512 digits of `1010101010...001010` which are then converted to the decimal it represents?

Or does it mean 512 digits of `0-9`, so basicly a 512-digit number with digits ranging from 0-9? Something like 12414124124....54543=512 digits.

Comment: Each bit represents a 0 or 1.

Comment: If you really want to know, lookup the source code which you can find in the file `src.zip` in your JDK installation directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From sourcecode, they are stored in an `int` array

> The magnitude of this BigInteger, in big-endian order: the zeroth element of this array is the most-significant int of the magnitude. The magnitude must be "minimal" in that the most-significant int (mag[0]) must be non-zero. This is necessary to ensure that there is exactly one representation for each BigInteger value. Note that this implies that the BigInteger zero has a zero-length mag array.

```
118 
119     int[] mag;
120 
121     // These "redundant fields" are initialized with recognizable nonsense
122     // values, and cached the first time they are needed (or never, if they
123     // aren't needed).
124
```

Comment: But does it store a digit per array entry or 32-bit integer parts?

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, `BigInteger` converts an integer into arbitrary-length bit string, and then split the bit string by 4bytes. Then, each 4bytes result is assigned into each element in `mag` array:

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("1234567890");

byte[] bytes = bi.toByteArray();

String rs = "";
for (byte b : bytes) {
    String bs1 = Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xff);
    String bs2 = String.format("%8s", bs1).replace(' ', '0');
    rs = rs + bs2 + " ";
}
System.out.println(bi.signum());     // 1
System.out.println(bi.bitLength());  // 31
System.out.println(rs);              // 01001001 10010110 00000010 11010010
```

- The `final int signum` is `1` (`00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001`).
- The `mag[0]` in `final int[] mag` is `1234567890` (`01001001 10010110 00000010 11010010`). Yes, `mag` has one element only.

Let's represent more bigger integer:

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("12345678901234567890");

byte[] bytes = bi.toByteArray();

String rs = "";
for (byte b : bytes) {
    String bs1 = Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xff);
    String bs2 = String.format("%8s", bs1).replace(' ', '0');
    rs = rs + bs2 + " ";
}
System.out.println(bi.signum());     // 1
System.out.println(bi.bitLength());  // 64
System.out.println(rs);              // 00000000 10101011 01010100 10101001 10001100 11101011 00011111 00001010 11010010
```

- The `final int signum` is `1` (`00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001`).
- The `mag[0]` in `final int[] mag` is `-1420514932` (`10101011 01010100 10101001 10001100`).
- The `mag[1]` in `final int[] mag` is `-350287150` (`11101011 00011111 00001010 11010010`).

When we instantiate an `BigInteger` instance with a negative integer:

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("-1234567890");

byte[] bytes = bi.toByteArray();

String rs = "";
for (byte b : bytes) {
    String bs1 = Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xff);
    String bs2 = String.format("%8s", bs1).replace(' ', '0');
    rs = rs + bs2 + " ";
}
System.out.println(bi.signum());     // -1
System.out.println(bi.bitLength());  // 31
System.out.println(rs);              // 10110110 01101001 11111101 00101110
```

- The `final int signum` is `-1` (`11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111`).
- The `mag[0]` in `final int[] mag` is `1234567890` (`01001001 10010110 00000010 11010010`). Yes, `mag` stores number's *magnitude*.
- When we call `toByteArray()`, `BigInteger` converts `mag` array's magnitude representation into 2's complement representation because `signum` is `-1`, meaning negative value. So, do not treat `toByteArray` as `BigInteger`'s internal representation.

When we instantiate an `BigInteger` instance with zero:

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("0");

byte[] bytes = bi.toByteArray();

String rs = "";
for (byte b : bytes) {
    String bs1 = Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xff);
    String bs2 = String.format("%8s", bs1).replace(' ', '0');
    rs = rs + bs2 + " ";
}
System.out.println(bi.signum());     // 0
System.out.println(bi.bitLength());  // 0
System.out.println(rs);              // 00000000
```

- The `final int signum` is `0` (`00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000`).
- The `final int[] mag` has no element; zero-sized array. `The magnitude must be "minimal" in that the most-significant int (mag[0]) must be non-zero. This is necessary to ensure that there is exactly one representation for each BigInteger value. Note that this implies that the BigInteger zero has a zero-length mag`