# Why does this BigInteger value cause a stack overflow exception? C#

Tags: c#, stack-overflow, biginteger

I am using `BigInteger` in `C#` in connection with the factorial function. The program has a lightning fast calculation of 5000!, but has an overflow error at 10000!.  According to [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5000!), 10000! is approximately

10000! = 2.8 x 10^35659

From what I can tell from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779406/how-are-biginteger-stored), a BigInteger is stored in an `int[]` array. If I interpret the `int` type correctly, it uses 4 bytes, meaning that 10000! uses about `4 x log10(2.8 x 10^35659) = 142636` bytes, where I use `log10(n)` (the log to base 10) as an approximation to the number of digits of n. This is only 143 MB, but I still get a stack overflow exception. Why does this happen?

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        BigInteger hugeFactorial = Calculations.Factorial(5000);
    }
}

class Calculations
{
    public static BigInteger Factorial(int n)
    {
        if (n == 1) return n;
        else return n*Factorial(n - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack overflow exception, right?

Comment: @IvanStoev yes, Stack overflow exception. It says: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred" Let me correct my post.

Comment: You just answered you question. Do you see a word "BigInteger" in the exception? Do you see a word "stack"? Which code is using stack?

Comment: Goes wrong on x64 jitter, it needs 208 bytes of stack space for the method.  5000 x 208 == kaboom, the stack size is 1MB.  You'll have to write an iterative version instead of the recursive one you have now.  A for(;;) loop.

Comment: @IvanStoev I didn't know of this "stack", but I just watched a youtube video on it.

Comment: @HansPassant it works ok for 5000, but 10000 makes the stack overflow. How did you find out how much stack space the method takes?

Comment: I looked at the machine code.  208 is specific to RyuJIT, the x64 jitter included with VS2015.  It uses AVX instructions, makes it more stack hungry.  Otherwise a detail, the code can be bombed arbitrarily by making the argument large enough.

Comment: @HansPassant ok, I don't think my version of Visual Studio supports viewing the machine code, as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351282/how-to-view-the-assembly-code-for-c-sharp-in-visual-studio-not-the-msil In any case, the "Debug -> Windows" menu doesn't have an Assembly button. Do you know of another way that I can see the machine code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recursive call of `Factorial` results in stackoverflow for a large enough call stack. Your call for 10000! is likely hitting that mark. You will probably have to change your implementation to iterative algorithm to fix overflow.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I didn't know of this "call stack", but from what I can understand, the bound on the call stack is not some intrinsic property of my computer, but rather a parameter in C# that I can change.

Answer (score 9):

Default stack size for threads is **1 MB**. You can change it while creating a new thread. I would write your code as(without blocking the calling thread):

```
TaskCompletionSource<BigInteger> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<BigInteger>();
var t = new Thread(() => 
    {
        var res = Calculations.Factorial(10000);
        tcs.SetResult(res);
    }, 
    1024*1024*16 //16MB stack size
);
t.Start();
var result = await tcs.Task;
Console.Write(result);
```

Answer (score 7):

As [loopedcode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/360950/loopedcode) said you should use at least iteration algorithm to calculate factorial.

```
public static BigInteger Factorial(int n)
{
    BigInteger result = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        result *= i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

There are even more efficient algorithms ([look here](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/conclusions.html)).